# Python - Dynamic class registration with inheritance from abstract base class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-decorators, factory-method

I would like to implement a common and standardized data interface with dynamic respectively modular reader objects. At the moment I have developed a decorator function inside the factory class `DataFrameInterface`, which registers Reader objects by the decorator `@DataFrameInterface.register_reader()`.

That works very well so far.
What I would like to achieve now is, that the decorator or the registration of the actual reader is only defined in the abstract base class `BasicReader(ABC)` and is inherited by the specific reader implementation. The problem here is that a decorator cannot simply be inherited.

In simple words, I don't want to manually place the decorator before every reader class and I want do that work already at the inheritance of the abstract class `BasicReader`.

To make my issue a little clearer, below you can find a more detailed example (*removed some doc strings and functional code to make listing more readable and compact).

Thanks in advance for any tips and suggestions.

```py
# Import used modules
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from pathlib import Path

class DataFrameInterface(object):
    """Basic Interface Class."""

    readers = []
    """List of registered reader objects"""

    def __new__(cls, filepath, rbit="r", **kwargs):
        filepath = Path(filepath)

        # Perform file checks for each registered reader
        for reader in cls.readers:
            if reader._check(filepath):
                return reader(filepath, rbit=rbit, **kwargs)

        # If no suitable reader is implemented, raise exception
        _msg = "The input must be a VTK or HDF data set and not {}.".format(filepath.suffix)
        raise NotImplementedError(_msg)

    @classmethod
    def register_reader(cls):
        """
        Register reader as subclass of DataFrameInterface.

        For a reader to become available, the class object of the reader must
        have the active decorator @DataFrameInterface.register_reader().
        """
        def decorator(subclass):
            cls.readers.append(subclass)
            return subclass

        return decorator


class BasicReader(ABC):
    """An abstract base class for constructing a common reader interface."""

    def __init__(self, filename, rbit="r", **kwargs):
        """Initialize the reader object."""

        self.rbit = rbit
        self.attrs, self.dataframe = self._load(filename, rbit)
        return

    @abstractmethod
    def get_timeSteps(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_mesh(self):
        pass

    def get_constants(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_data(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_mesh(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _check(filepath):
        return False


@DataFrameInterface.register_reader()
class HDFReader(BasicReader):
    """A simple reader for hdf datasets."""

    @staticmethod
    def _check(filename):
        return filename.suffix == ".h5"

    @staticmethod
    def _load(filename, rbit):
        pass

    def get_timeSteps(self, dname="times", dfrom="constants"):
        pass

    def get_constants(self, arr_name, index=None, dtype="index"):
        pass

    def get_data(self, arr_name, timeSteps=None, dtype="point_data"):
        pass

    def get_mesh(self, time=None, mtype="constant"):
        pass

# For testing purpose
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = DataFrameInterface("filename.h5")
```

Answer (score 0):

As I just found out, since Python 3.6 there is the  [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method. This method is called during inheritance and before the class is initialized. Fortunately, version 3.6 is the minimum requirement for this project.
I was not aware of this and found out myself by chance. So here is the solution to my problem.

The solution is simple and can be handled easily. Only this code snipped must be added to the superclasse (BasicReader) from which is inherited and everything else happens automagically without additional decorators:

```py
def __init_subclass__(cls):
    DataFrameInterface.register_reader(cls)
    return
```

Next the  `register_reader` method has to be modified:

```py
@classmethod
def register_reader(cls1, cls):
    """Register reader as subclass of DataFrameInterface."""
    cls1.readers.append(cls)
```